# find xml node by inner text in xml document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

how can i retrieve node out of xml document by inner text.
for example

```
 <w:t>WARNING</w:t>
```

node consists multiple times with different values in xml document.
I want to retrieve only those w:t nodes with inner text contains "WARNING" .

how can it be done?

Comment: What have you done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query elements with prefix you have to register proper prefix-to-namespace-URI mapping using `XmlNamespaceManager`, then use that registered prefix in your XPath, for example :

```
var xml = @"<root xmlns:w=""test"">
    <w:t>WARNING</w:t>
</root>";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
//register proper prefix-to-namespace-URI mapping
nsManager.AddNamespace("w", "test");

//following XPath used to select <w:t> nodes with inner text contains "WARNING"
var result = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//w:t[contains(., 'WARNING')]", nsManager);
//print result
Console.WriteLine(result.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var wtNodes = elements.Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.Equals("w:t"));
var warningNodes = wtNodes.Where(node => node.Value.Contains("WARNING"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xmlNodeList  xNlist=  xDoc.selectNodes("//pre:t[.="WARNING"]",objXmlnsMgr);
```

Here:
xDoc is XmlDocument;
objXmlnsMgr is XmlNamespaceManager ('w' in your case) & pre is its prefix.